# Aggregate Text data using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have the following data:

```
Name  | Condition  
Mike  | Good  
Mike  | Good  
Steve | Good  
Steve | Alright  
Joe   | Good  
Joe   | Bad
```

I want to write an if statement, if `Bad` exists, I want to classify the name as `Bad`. If `Bad` does not exist but `Alright` Exists, then classify as `Alright`. If only `Good` exists, then classify as `good`.

So my data would turn into:

```
Name  | Condition  
Mike  | Good  
Steve | Alright  
Joe   | Bad
```

Is this possible in SQL?

Comment: Must an answer provide solutions for all 3 databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Access query would be easy if you first create a table which maps *Condition* to a *rank* number.

```
Condition rank
--------- ----
Bad          1
Alright      2
Good         3
```

Then a `GROUP BY` query would give you the minimum *rank* for each *Name*:

```sql
SELECT y.Name, Min(c1.rank) AS MinOfrank
FROM
    [YourTable] AS y
    INNER JOIN conditions AS c1
    ON y.Condition = c1.Condition
GROUP BY y.Name;
```

If you want to display the *Condition* string for those ranks, join back to the *conditions* table again:

```sql
SELECT sub.Name, sub.MinOfrank, c2.Condition
FROM
    (
        SELECT y.Name, Min(c1.rank) AS MinOfrank
        FROM
            [YourTable] AS y
            INNER JOIN conditions AS c1
            ON y.Condition = c1.Condition
        GROUP BY y.Name
    ) AS sub
    INNER JOIN conditions AS c2
    ON sub.MinOfrank = c2.rank;
```

Performance should be fine with indexes on those *conditions* fields.

Seems to me this approach could also work in those other databases (MySQL and SQL Server) tagged in the question.

Comment: ah! wish i thought of this, smart answer is the easy answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a case statement to rank the conditions then max() or min() to summarize the results before returning them back to the user in the same format.

Query:

```
SELECT [Name]
, case min(case condition when 'bad' then 0 when 'alright' then 1 else 2 end)
when 0 then 'bad' when 1 then 'alright' when 2 then 'good' end as Condition
from mytable
group by [name]
```

Comment: does that work in microsoft access? What is the "condition" field ?

Comment: Sorry didn't test it in MS Access. I was replying for MS SQL Server. You could test it. I know that MS Access supports MIN and CASE, so it should work in theory.

The condition field was the one you used in your header. If you have a real production situation where you had a longer list of say, 100 different items that were ranked, you could store them in a table for more efficient code. Then you store the ranks and lookup the condition descriptions or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

mysql has an IF - function.

Here, have a look at it: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if